# FusionCharts is taking long time to render the graphs in Internet Explorer(Chrome is faster)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts to create and render graphs.

I need to load more than 60 graphs per page.

When I tried to load the page using IE 11, the loading process is taking around 5 minutes.
But using Google chrome, the page loads in less than a minute.

Could you please guide me how to proceed to find/resolve the issue??

Please let me know if you need any more details

Thanks in Advance!

FusionCharts version : 3.2

IE version : IE 11

**Code:**

```
graph = new FusionCharts(<name>, graphId, width, height, "0");
graph.setDataURL(BrowserUtilities.encodeURLParameter(url));

graph.render("divid");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very hard to say the exact reason for this, But from your code snippet it seems a lot of processes are running at the same time and it depends on how Individual browsers are dealing this. We, as developers face more problems with IE than any other.

However, I can suggest you to improve your client side implementation, to create charts and load data in linear fashion other than doing them all at a time. You can create a chart instance and listen for appropriate events to know that the creation process has been completed and then load data and move on to create the next chart. Note, you don't have to wait for the data to load as that is asynchronous. If you can separate / batch your execution tasks, browsers are expected to give you better output and the end user should not be frustrated.

This is not the single solution or way, there could be many others to understand and tackle the issue here.

Comment: Sry I didn't get how performance increases when running process sequentially instead of concurrently.

I came to know that both IE & chrome can process  max 6 requests concurrently. So while processing 7th request it is waiting until any of the 6  processes completes.